# How do you retrain a Automl model with "new" set of data?

Tags: h2o, automl

I have a train set of 1000 rows (1 row per day for example).
I get a prediction for a set of 5 futures (model.predict).
Over the next 5 days, I actually get the data for next 5 days (numbers (sales for example).
Now I want the model to be trained on those 5 actual real life data points instead of on (1005 rows i.e 1000 original plus 5 new).

Can this be done. Sorry for the "basic" question and all the help (including links if already answered) appreciated.

### Code

```
import h2o
from h2o.automl import H2OAutoML
import pandas as pd

h2o.init()

data_path = "./df.csv"

df = h2o.import_file(data_path)
y = "c"

splits = df.split_frame(ratios = [0.8,0.19], seed = 1)

train = splits[0] #some part to train first
test = splits[1] # this is test set 1 (test later to become train set)
test2 = splits[2] # assume this to be the real world values 

aml = H2OAutoML(max_runtime_secs=120,project_name='try',  seed=1234)
aml.train(y = y, training_frame = train)

#First set of predictions

yy=aml.predict(test)

x=yy.as_data_frame(use_pandas=True) # predictions based on train set 
#print them
print(x) 

#the test set is now "new real world data" 
#to be added as incremental training of the model

aml.train(y = y, training_frame = test) 

#get the predictions again
yy=aml.predict(test2)

x=yy.as_data_frame(use_pandas=True) 
print(x)
```

I have tried to retrain on the "new set"  ofdata (assuming that is what line 30 does) but get rather curious numbers.

Comment: Thank you dadboz for the edit suggestion.